# Use RequireJS module in TypeScript class

Tags: javascript, typescript, backbone.js, requirejs

Is it possible to use RequireJS (created in legacy JS application) module inside TypeScript class? Both are in same project but want to use RequireJS module inside TS class.

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'backbone'
], function($, Backbone) {
  "use strict";

  var TestModule = Backbone.Model.extend({
....
```

I want to use the above inside TS class.

Comment: Are you exporting your TS as AMD modules?

Comment: No, it is legacy application. TS has been added to it later.

Comment: Have you tried to run this code? Got any errors?